# Where exactly in the account controller should I check if a user is in a specific role after login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I am trying to create a simple ban system where if you have the role "Banned" and you try to login it should log you out.

The problem is I don't where exactly in the account controller to check if you in the "Banned"

```
// POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                if (User.IsInRole("Banned"))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                }
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I tried putting it below

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
```

But it didn't work. I am very new to ASP.NET MVC and any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Tried editing the SignInManager but it didnt have an effect

```
public virtual async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        if (this.UserManager == null)
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        TUser user = await this.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).WithCurrentCulture<TUser>();
        if ((object)user == null)
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        if (this.UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Banned"))
        {
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }
        if (await this.UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<bool>())
            return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
        if (await this.UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password).WithCurrentCulture<bool>())
        {
            IdentityResult identityResult = await this.UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<IdentityResult>();
            return await this.SignInOrTwoFactor(user, isPersistent).WithCurrentCulture<SignInStatus>();
        }
        if (shouldLockout)
        {
            IdentityResult identityResult = await this.UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<IdentityResult>();
            if (await this.UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture<bool>())
                return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
        }
        return SignInStatus.Failure;
    }
```

Comment: `But it didn't work` <= what do you mean by this? Exception? Error message? Was the result ignored? Was the user allowed to log in anyway? Is the existing user that did not have to re-auth. still allowed access? It did not work leaves everyone guessing as to what that means.

Comment: By "It didnt work" I meant that it had not effect. I was able to log in normally with no errors or execeptions

Comment: The best approach is to extend the `UserManager` and add your check there, do not authenticate the user if they are associated with that role. You can also extend the convenience method of the SigninManager if you wanted to return a specific message via the enumeration result or just return Failure.

Comment: I am guessing that User.IsInRole returns false when you believe that should not be the case. This is due to the fact that `User` is not yet populated because it is created from the context in the request and you are still in the process of authenticating for the first time.

Comment: Ok so I went into the SignInManager and I added my check if the user is banned to return a failed sign up status but again it did nothing. I edited in my changes in the OP

Comment: `again it did nothing` <= Again, please tell us **in detail** what happened. What happened with `this.UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Banned")`? Did it not find the user in the role? Did you check if the user id is indeed is accosiated with that role (how did you check). Did this return true and return `SignInStatus.Failure` but the user was signed in after that point? What does that mean? We can't look over your shoulder to see the app in debug mode and walk through each line with you so you have to be descriptive.

Comment: I was able to debug the AccountController and the SignUpManager returned "Success" as a result but I can't go with the debugger in the SignInManager.cs file to debug it and find out why it returned "Success".

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't really have an easy, built-in way to do what you're requesting.  It has the AuthorizeAttribute class which you can use on a controller or an action method.  It allows you to specify either the users or roles that *are* allowed access, but it sounds like you want to do the opposite.

The problem with the code you've provided is that you would need to include it in every single action method and that would get ugly fast.

If you really want to pursue this approach, and I'm not sure it's a good one, you could write your own FilterAttribute class.

Hope this gets you started in the right direction.